# To know if a string is composed of a word or two words

Tags: javascript, html

I have a variable `thread.particpants[0].name` which is a string. It can contain strings of characters like this: `"Jean Jean"` or chains like that `"Jean"`.

I would like to know when this chain is composed of 2 words, and when it is composed of 1 word

Comment: Hint: Try checking if the string contains a space.

Comment: Do the words have to be the same to count? Is it only a space that will ever be a word boundary? What if there are more than 2 words? And most importantly... what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trim the string and then check for space

```
var hasMultipleWords = input.trim().indexOf( " " ) != -1; //returns true if there is a space
```

Comment: Thanks :) it works !

Answer (score 0):

Check if contains a space

```
thread.particpants[0].name.indexOf(" ")
```

Or, alternatively, split on space and check the array length

```
thread.particpants[0].name.split(" ").length
```